# Does any relation between $x$ and $y$ have to hold for all $(x,y)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**If we define a relationship such as $y=x^2$ between the variables $y$ and $x$, does this relation have to hold for all values of $y$ and $x$?**

Can we have this, allowing the relationship to have a false truth value, for some values of the given variables, could we consider the set of $(x,y)$ that satisfy the relation a subset of the total possible $(x,y)$ combinations? I assume it's up to the individual whether a relation is true for all or some values of $x,y$ and is there a way to make this explicit?

For example a relation where $z=f(t)=g(x,y)$ is one where it is almost in the definition of $x$ and $y$ that $x=h(y)$ as they both depend on a variable $t$, could we have a situation where such a relation is only true for some values the variables can take?

Comment: $x, y $ : We have no shelter  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a function, say $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R; f(x)=x^2,$ what you’re doing is defining a set $f = $ {$(x,y) |y=x^2$ ; $x,y \in \mathbb R$}. Any ordered pair $(x,y)$ that satisfies the criterion is an element of the set, while the rest are not.

I don’t understand what you mean by

> I assume it's up to the individual whether a relation is true for all or some values of ,
> and is there a way to make this explicit?

Comment: What I'm asking is whether it is up to the person defining the variables to decide if the possible combinations of $(x,y)$ are all of the form: $(x,y)  \in${$(x,y) |y=x^2$ or if all possible combinations $(x,y)$ can exist outside of the set of tuples that satisfy the relation? For example if $x=3$ and $y=6$ is a possible combination which makes the statement false.

Comment: BY DEFINITION, any ordered pair that satisfies $y=x^2$ belongs to the set.

Comment: I think I get what you mean now. Essentially you are trying to ask that once $y=x^2$ has been defined, whether the range of x and y are limited. The thing is, for every x there exists a unique y (though the converse isn’t true) such that (x,y) belong to the set.

Comment: But yes, when you wrote y=$x^2$, the range of possible values of y was changed to [0, $\infty$]. Does this answer your question? If needed I’d love to try to clarify further.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much, just one thing, essentially, if I wanted to change the possible values of $y$ would I say 'for some $(x,y)$, $y=x^2$ and have a range of choice for $y$ being $[∞,∞]$ but in this case the relation is not true not for all $(x,y)$? Basically there's some choices of $x$ and $y$ that satisfy it and some that don't.

Comment: Yes. That’s it. Like you can say $a=b^2$ and then write $(a,b)=(81,9)$ but can’t write $a=b^2$ and then immediately write $(a,b)=(1,9)$. You have to clarify that this does not satisfy the relation.

Comment: And whether I want my variable's range, in the case of $y$ to be just values that satisfy or to include values that don't satisfy it is completely my choice?

Comment: No. Once you’ve defined $y=x^2$, (OMG I’ve never written $y=x^2$ so many times in a day lol) the values of y are RESTRICTED to [0,$\infty$). You can’t change it.

Comment: Can I say something like For SOME values of  $(x,y)$ $y=x^2$ like how I said before we can have a set that satisfies the relation as a smaller subset of the set of all values the variables can take? Like for example I might say $y=x^2$ and I want that to hold for all values hence limiting $y$ to $[0,∞]$ but for Some values (namely $x=2$, $y=4$ the relation $y=x+2$ holds as well, but just as easily I could have $y$ and $x$ allowed to be anything, letting $y$ have range $[-∞,∞]$ and for some values $y=x^2$ holds? (I'm getting sick of writing it too, tried to come up with a better example)

Comment: I’ll be succinct. Yes.

Comment: Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

A relation that is always true is a "tautology" and is consider not very interesting (trivial).  Yes, $y= x^2$" is a relation.  Is it true when x= 3 and y= 7?

Comment: Of course not, but we can have situations where the fact that $y=x^2%$ is almost inherently in the definition of the variables themselves, so it must always be true, look at the common example above used with functions of two variables where the arguments are dependent, could we define it so that we can have sometimes $y=x^2$ be true or false such as the situation you have given, where $x=3$ and $y=7$ is a possible combination? How do we know exactly what range of values a variable can vary in? Typically if we define a relation we don't leave the situation where it is true, but can we do so?